# Using jQuery event handlers inside Javascript class constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop, jquery-events

I'm new to OOP in Javascript, I've been changing some of my older codes to make reusable code.I decided to turn them, instead of some inline codes, into some Javascript classes.

So here's my class:

```
    function TreeStructure(psi, csi, csc, kwargs) {
        this.parentSelectorId       = psi;
        this.childrenSelectorId     = csi;
        this.childrenSelectorClass  = csc;
    
        kwargs = (typeof kwargs === "undefined") ? 'NoOptionalArguments' : kwargs;
    
        // First Question

        $('#' + this.parentSelectorId).click(this.parentSelectHandler());

        // Second Question 
        $('#' + this.parentSelectorId).on('click', this.parentSelectHandler(e));        
    }; 

    TreeStructure.prototype.parentSelectHandler = function () {
        alert("Why is it called after page loads ?!?
                       it's attached to a click handler   huh?");    
    }
```

And usage of the class:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         tree = new TreeStructure('blahId', 'blahId', 'blahClass');
    });
```

But when running this, Unexpected events (for me) happen. So here's my two questions:

1. Why is `parentSelectHandler` function called after page loads? (I think the expected behavior is to be called after the selector has been clicked)
2. In jQuery Event handlers, I can get the event and pass it to the event handler function, but when I try to pass `parentSelectHandler`, an argument `'e'`, it says it's not defined.

So can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is executing because you are executing, and subsequently setting its return value as the callback, it instead of setting it itself as the callback

```
$('#' + this.parentSelectorId).on('click', this.parentSelectHandler(e));
```

should be

```
$('#' + this.parentSelectorId).on('click', this.parentSelectHandler);
```

if you are wanting to capture the `event` object then modify the anonymous function to

```
TreeStructure.prototype.parentSelectHandler = function (e) {
```

this will make `e` hold the `event` object

Comment: And as of my 2nd problem , can I be able to pass arguments (event) to the function, if i call it that way ?

Comment: event is automatically passed, i did a edit a second ago to show modifing the anonymous function to get the event object, it will be in the `e` variable within the function.

Answer (score 3):

You're not passing a function but you execute it and then pass return value to click, you need to pass a function.

```
$('#' + this.parentSelectorId).click(this.parentSelectHandler);
```

and if you pass that method to click handler the context will be change so you need to wrap it with anonymous function that will keep the context:

```
var self = this;
$('#' + this.parentSelectorId).click(function(e) {
  self.parentSelectHandler(e);
});
```

or use bind method

```
$('#' + this.parentSelectorId).click(this.parentSelectHandler.bind(this));
```

Comment: :Great Idea about that self, thank you, but will I be able to use multiple instances of TreeStructure if I use self that way ? wouldn't it be considered as only One global variable ?

Comment: @SpiXel each instance will have different self. self is the same as this.